# How do I change the default permissions for device files (e.g. a gamepad)?

Tags: input-device, gamepad, permissions

I have a gamepad that I am interested in using with the Pi.  When I plug it into my development laptop running Lubuntu 13.04, I get the following:

```
418476 crw-rw-r--+ 1 root root 13,  0 Oct 12 22:55 js0
```

However, when I plug the same gamepad into the Pi, I get this:

```
5188 crw-rw---T 1 root input 13,  0 Oct 13 06:01 js0
```

I am able to both change the group of the device and the permissions, but whenever the gamepad is unplugged and then reinserted it defaults back to what is shown above.  How do I preserve permissions for a device file after it has been removed?

Answer (score 3):

you should use `lsusb` command to find the device manufacturer and product code like this:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 045e:0047 Microsoft Corp. IntelliMouse Explorer 3.0
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
$
```

For example, I can see my mouse has ID 045e:0047, then add the line to the `/etc/udev/rules.d/69-gamepad.rules`:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="045e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0047", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

replacing the `Vendor` and `Product` numbers with the ones you've found with `lsusb` command.

Finally, you have to add yourself to the group 'plugdev':

```
sudo adduser user plugdev
```

where `user` is your user name (use `who` to find out if unsure).

After that you might need reboot, relogon or just reinsert your device depending on the settings you've changed.

Comment: Is is possible to generalize this to work with any gamepad, regardless of the vendor/model?  Also, why do I have to add myself to "plugdev"?

Comment: @InkBlend "plugdev" group has access to the external devices, and this could work with any gamepad, you just have to add the necessary attributes to your "/etc/udev/rules.d/69-gamepad.rules" file

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was "Is it possible to create a single rule that applies to all gamepads?".  Also, because I end up setting the permissions to 666 anyway, doesn't that mean that I don't need to either change the group to "plugdev" or add myself to that same group?

Comment: basically you need to specify different rule for every gamepad, because though it's possible to omit "Vendor" or "Product" fields, you generally don't want your digicam or keyboard or mouse or WiFi dongle to be mistakenly treated as gamepad.

Comment: Well, doesn't the file "69-gamepad.rules" only apply to gamepads?

Comment: file name does not matter, only Vendor and Product IDs do.