# How to access bluetooth controller on `/dev/input/js0` as user/group?

Tags: bluetooth, pi-3b+, user, joystick

I'm working on an application that is reading an XBox controller connected via bluetooth. After configuring it (see https://pimylifeup.com/xbox-controllers-raspberry-pi/), I noticed that only root has read/write access to `/dev/input/js0`. Reading another answer ([How do I change the default permissions for device files (e.g. a gamepad)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10100/how-do-i-change-the-default-permissions-for-device-files-e-g-a-gamepad)), it leverages `lsusb` to identify the device and set `/etc/udev/rules.d/69-gamepad.rules`; this doesn't identify devices connected to the bluetooth adapter on the Raspberry Pi 3B+.

How should I search differently, or is there a better way to configure this for user/group reads?

Comment: I am aware that the file is accessible through the `input` group, but it's typically a really bad idea to add users to that group...